# Error: cannot import name 'SpearmanRConstantInputWarning' from 'scipy.stats'

Tags: python, scipy, google-colaboratory, skbio

I'm getting an error when importing the `skbio` package on Google Colab. The error message is related to `SpearmanRConstantInputWarning` of the `scipy.stats` package. What should I do to solve this problem?
I've tried to uninstall and install `skbio` and `scipy`, but it has not worked.

[image]

Comment: Which version of SciPy are you using?  If you don't know, a simple way to check is to run `import scipy; print(scipy.__version__)`

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser , I'm using the version 1.4.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be some issue with the version. If you run

```
pip install scikit-bio==0.5.6
```

it shouldn't show that problem, at least it worked when I tried for 0.5.6 and 0.5.5 in Colab.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but could not downgrade to `scikit-bio==0.5.6` as it conflicted with my Python version (3.10).  An alternative workaround is downgrading `scipy`:

```
conda install -c conda-forge scipy=1.8
```

Presumably which package to downgrade will depend on your circumstances.

(Would have added as a comment to 3991santiago's answer but I do not have the reputation)