# ImportError: cannot import name 'ConstantInputWarning' from 'scipy.stats'

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy, skbio

Error due to `scikit-kbio`:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'ConstantInputWarning' from 'scipy.stats' (/home/smith/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/stats/__init__.py)
```

This is likely related to recent installations (like `numba`) which might have modified versions of `numpy` and `scipy`, as previously the problem didn't occur.

Versions:
`python` : 3.8
`scipy` : 1.8.1
`numpy` : 1.22.4
`skbio` : 0.5.9

Related:
[Error: cannot import name 'SpearmanRConstantInputWarning' from 'scipy.stats'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72744811/6151828)
[Cannot import name 'ConstantInputWarning' from 'scipy.stats' #4](https://github.com/raw-lab/mercat2/issues/4)

Answer (score 0):

The currently adopted solution was to revert to an earlier revision of conda, as described in the answer to [Conda install screwed up my environment. Can I undo it?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54172505/6151828)

The functioning combination of versions in my case is:
`python` : 3.8.17
`scipy` : 1.10.0
`numpy` : 1.24.4
`skbio` : 0.5.9